# Get original content type from multipart/alternative

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm using javamail 1.4.7 to read mail from Gmail with imap.
I'm getting MimeType multipart/alternative even though my content is simple plain text (e.g "hello world").
I got 2 body parts, one having content type text/plain other has text/html.
My question is how can I determine which body part is oroginal(originally sent by sender).
I just want to fetch mail with it's original content type (i.e If mail content is plain text then I want to fetch part having content type "text/plain" and if mail content having html then I want to fetch part having content type "text/html").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know your mailer isn't sending your simple plain text message as multipart/alternative?

If your mailer isn't sending both parts, then some mail server is converting the original body to multipart/alternative.  There's no defined way to know whether or how it did that.

Comment: Yes, you are right, mail server(Gmail) converts it. So Mime Type multipart/alternative is Gmail specific?

Comment: No, multipart/alternative is not Gmail specific.  It's defined by RFC 2046.